# SQL command running slow. Need help identifying slowness

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, query-performance

I have a SQL query that is taking hours to run. Basically, I'm looking to find documents (PDF) in our "page" table that has special characters. I find those PDFs in the PDFFile table. Executing just the first AND clause returns in 16 seconds. Adding a second clause makes the SQL take 3hrs. Trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The query:

```
select b.bookletname, b.trackingID, b.[version], s.name
from page p
inner join section s on s.id = p.sectionid
inner join booklet b on b.id = s.bookletid
INNER JOIN [user] u ON b.CreatedBy = u.id
INNER JOIN client c ON c.id = u.clientID
WHERE u.clientID = 2
AND p.[filename] IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT pdf.[FileName]
    FROM PDFFile pdf
    WHERE pdf.fileName LIKE '%\<%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\>%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\"%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\%%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%''%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\*%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\+%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\\%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\/%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\:%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\?%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\[%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\]%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\|%' ESCAPE '\'
)
OR p.[PDF_File_Name] IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT pdf.[FileName]
    FROM PDFFile pdf
    WHERE pdf.fileName LIKE '%\<%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\>%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\"%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\%%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%''%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\*%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\+%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\\%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\/%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\:%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\?%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\[%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\]%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\|%' ESCAPE '\'
)
OR p.[PDFName] IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT pdf.[FileName]
    FROM PDFFile pdf
    WHERE pdf.fileName LIKE '%\<%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\>%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\"%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\%%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%''%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\*%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\+%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\\%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\/%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\:%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\?%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\[%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\]%' ESCAPE '\'
    OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\|%' ESCAPE '\'
)
```

Comment: with that many `LIKE`s, how could this not be slow?

Comment: Why does your PDF table have two separate filename columns?  If one of them is nullable, can you use `COALESCE()`?

Comment: @Lamak: especially with `LIKE` and a leading `%` --> makes sure **no indexes** can ever be used!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite this using `exists` and simplify the `like`s.  SQL Server allows you to have lists of characters in the pattern, and most of the character you have do not need escaping (I hope I got the resulting pattern exactly right).

I would recommend:

```
select b.bookletname, b.trackingID, b.[version], s.name
from page p inner join
     section s
     on s.id = p.sectionid inner join
     booklet b
     on b.id = s.bookletid inner join
     [user] u
     on b.CreatedBy = u.id inner join
     client c 
     on c.id = u.clientID
where u.clientID = 2 and
      (exists (select 1
               from PDFFile pdf
               where pdf.fileName LIKE '%[<>"''*+\\/:?\[\]|]%' ESCAPE '\' and
                     pdf.fileName = p.filename
              ) or
       exists (select 1
               from PDFFile pdf
               where pdf.fileName LIKE '%[<>"''*+\\/:?\[\]|]%' ESCAPE '\' and
                     pdf.fileName = p.PDF_File_Name
              ) or
       exists (select 1
               from PDFFile pdf
               where pdf.fileName LIKE '%[<>"''*+\\/:?\[\]|]%' ESCAPE '\' and
                     pdf.fileName = p.PDFName
              )
      );
```

You want to be sure that you have an index on `PDFFile(fileName)` for performance.

I also changed the logic.  Your original logic was like `where A and B or C or D` which is parsed as `where (A and B) or C or C`.  I changed it to `where A and (B or C or D)`.  This might also have accounted for a performance bottleneck.

Comment: Hey @Gordon Linoff. Definitely interested in your answer, but it has a syntax error...

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near '\'.
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ' and
                     pdf.fileName = p. PDFName
              )
      )
'.

Comment: Not sure how to fix, or I would.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the three table hits and put that select into temp table since you are using the same select to check three columns. So u can use temp table in where condition.

```
SELECT DISTINCT pdf.[FileName]
INTO   #temp
FROM   PDFFile pdf
WHERE  pdf.fileName LIKE '%\<%' ESCAPE '\'
        OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\>%' ESCAPE '\'
        OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\"%' ESCAPE '\'
        OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\%%' ESCAPE '\'
        OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%''%' ESCAPE '\'
        OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\*%' ESCAPE '\'
        OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\+%' ESCAPE '\'
        OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\\%' ESCAPE '\'
        OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\/%' ESCAPE '\'
        OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\:%' ESCAPE '\'
        OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\?%' ESCAPE '\'
        OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\[%' ESCAPE '\'
        OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\]%' ESCAPE '\'
        OR pdf.fileName LIKE '%\|%' ESCAPE '\' 

SELECT b.bookletname,
       b.trackingID,
       b.[version],
       s.NAME
FROM   page p
       INNER JOIN section s
               ON s.id = p.sectionid
       INNER JOIN booklet b
               ON b.id = s.bookletid
       INNER JOIN [user] u
               ON b.CreatedBy = u.id
       INNER JOIN client c
               ON c.id = u.clientID
WHERE  u.clientID = 2
       AND p.[filename] IN (SELECT *
                            FROM   #temp)
        OR p.[PDF_File_Name] IN (SELECT *
                                 FROM   #temp)
        OR p.[PDFName] IN (SELECT *
                           FROM   #temp)
```

Comment: This works. Definite performance increase. Went from over 3 hours to 10 mins. Going to attempt the other solution with +1 to see if his solution performs better. Thanks for the answer d(-_-)b